# IOS/Objective C: Access BOOL property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, boolean

Syntax question:

I am getting and accessing text values typed by users as follows:

in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

(This is wired to a text box)

and in .m file

```
NSString *name = self.textField.text;
```

How would I do the same thing for a Boolean value obtained from a switch?

in .h file I have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *pubField;
```

in .m file I am getting an error with

```
BOOL *pub = self.pubField.text;
```

as .text is not a valid attribute for a boolean or UI switch

Of note, I am using

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL * pub;
```

in my data model if that makes a difference.

Thanks for providing correct syntax.

Comment: `BOOL` is a primitive type. You don't want the asterisk in the property declaration or any other `BOOL` variable declaration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone reading this I got it to work as follows:

First of all, you should think of the so-called Boolean field in the data model file as just an NSNumber.  Boolean is just an alias they give it.  Behind the curtain it is just an NSNumber.

The control is a switch and the property of the switch you want to indicate that the value is True is .isOn but you need to convert the .isOn value using numberWithBool to get the NSNumber that you need to store in the database.

The difference between .on and .isON is that the second indicates that it is actually true whereas the first is just that it has a value of true or false.  So to test if it is true, yes,1,on, etc you check .isOn.

So the answer to my question is as follows:

in the .h file use:

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *pubField;

wired to the switch control.  Only difference with what I wrote question is weak vs strong.

in .m file use:

```
NSNumber *pub = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.pubField.isOn];
```

Finally while, you can give the pub attribute in entity the type "boolean" in the model, the property of the nsobject for the data model entity should be a NSNumber

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *pub;

Answer (score 2):

You are using a pointer to a primitive. That is hardly necessary or desirable. The proper declaration is:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL pub;
```

The following line from your question is faulty: `BOOL *pub = self.pubField.text;`. You should assign the `BOOL` not a pointer to it (`*pub` means "pointer to pub" which you use for objects, not for primitives). Second a `UISwitch` does not have a property `text`. It is confusing to name a `UISwitch` "pubField".

This is how you get a bool from a switch (based on above declaration):

```
self.pub = switchControl.on;
```

In the context of Core Data you might want to go with the plain vanilla Core Data convention to have all booleans as `NSNumber`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *pub;
```

and

```
managedObject.pub = @(switchControl.on);
```

Comment: I am using the suffix field because all of these are values that go into fields i.e. attributes in Core Data.  Realize IOS terms differ from database ones but ultimately core data does go into a database that is synchronized with a database on the server.  Is the primitive type adequate for working with the value from the switch, i.e. ON or should I be using an object?

Comment: It is appropriate. Xcode automatically generates objects, however, that are `NSNumber`. I will edit my answer to show how this is done.

Comment: I am using key value to store in dbase i.e. [record setValue:pub forKey:@"pub"];  How can I set pub equal to value from switch so it saves correctly?

Comment: Exactly as above, the value being `@(switch.on)`.

Comment: It is not confusing to call a `UISwitch` pub field. Adding "type" to variable name is actually frowned upon in most coding standards. `switch` is definitely a very bad name considering it's a keyword. In all other aspects I prefer this answer to the accepted one which has a very confusing explanation.

Comment: Yes, the fact that `switch` is a keyword for flow control is really problematic. Otherwise, I think that there is no problem calling a `UILabel` a label or a `UISwitch` a switch. As long as it is concise and clear and - point well taken - not redundant, everything goes.